# Problema ao copiar um bloco html quando clicar em um botão

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, formulário

Consegui fazer com que quando clico no botão adicionar mais campos, seja replicado o formulário. Porém o botão criar passou a fazer a mesma coisa do botão adicionar+campos e não a sua função de inserir os dados no banco. Poderiam me ajudar?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>"/>
   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('.info-block:first').clone().insertAfter('.info-block:last');
      });
    });

</script>


    <div class='container'>


<div class='info-block'>
       <h2 style="margin-top:0px">Criar Categorias de Inscrição </h2>
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="varchar">Nome Categoria <?php echo form_error('nome_categoria') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name='nome_categoria[]' id="nome_categoria" placeholder="Nome Categoria" value="<?php echo $nome_categoria; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="varchar">Descricao Categoria <?php echo form_error('descricao_categoria') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name='descricao_categoria[]' id="descricao_categoria" placeholder="Descricao Categoria" value="<?php echo $descricao_categoria; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="decimal">Valor Categoria <?php echo form_error('valor_categoria') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name='valor_categoria[]' id="valor_categoria" placeholder="Valor Categoria" value="<?php echo $valor_categoria; ?>" />
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name='idCategorias_Inscricao[]' value="<?php echo $idCategorias_Inscricao; ?>" /> 

            </form> 

   </div>

   </div>

         <button>Adicionar + campos</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Criar</button> 
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('categorias_inscricao') ?>" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione um class no botão da ação:

```
<button class="add">Adicionar + campos</button>
```

E modifique a função para funcionar com essa class:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $('.add').on('click', function(){
        $('.info-block:first').clone().insertAfter('.info-block:last');
      });
    });

</script>
```

Você também pode mudar o elemento do botão de adicionar, usar um `<span>` ou um `<p>` para estruturar melhor o código e até ajudar na estilização.

Comment: fiz essas alterações, mas agora o botão de criar não faz mais nada,o que pode ser?

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui e rodou de boas. Faz assim, deixa só essa parte do JS '$('.add').on('click', function() {
  $('.info-block:first').clone().insertAfter('.info-block:last');
});' e coloca no final do arquivo. Aqui ta o link do teste http://codepen.io/FuckingLunatic/pen/QNJYQg

Comment: Fiz isso, mas não rolou tbm, o teu teste aqui pra mim tbm não faz nada quando clica no criar, o que pode ser :O ?

Comment: ah ta, coloca o botão "criar" dentro das tags do form, ou faça uma call de submit via JS. Mas o botão precisa estar dentro do form

Comment: Agora trocou o erro, colocando dentro da tag form ,fica caindo no exeption de preenchimento do formulário,como se os campos não tivessem sido preenchidos.

Comment: Resolvemos um problema que criou outro. Agora você finaliza esse problema e tenta resolver a validação do formulário